# How was the first year of Latin.SE?

Tags: discussion

Happy birthday!
Our site Latin Language Stack Exchange went online February 23, 2016 — exactly one year ago.
The public beta stage started on March 15.
I want the site continue growing and prospering.

It would be great to have some free form feedback about our first year from you, the users.
We can focus on more specific issues and ideas in separate meta posts, so I don't want to give any restrictions here.
How was our first year to you?
Are there good practices we should continue, bad ones we should drop, or new ones we should adopt?
Feel free to share any thoughts you have.