# Moderator feedback after one year

Tags: discussion, moderation

Our *pro tempore* moderators have been around for [over a year now](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/badges/85/constable).
It would be good to have some feedback.
Here are some questions, but don't restrict yourself to them if you have something to say:

- Are you satisfied with the moderators?
- Do the moderators treat users well?
- Is there something the moderators should stop doing?
- Is there something the moderators should start doing?
- Do you have any thoughts on moderation on this site that you want to share?

I hope you don't feel pressured to fake a smile and give positive feedback.
Please write how you actually think about moderation.
We three are still learning, and we want to learn more.
You can discuss moderators individually or as a group.

If you have feedback that you prefer not to share in public, you can find my email at my homepage, and there is a link in my profile.

For general feedback about the site, you might want to see [the question on our first anniversary](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/260/79).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for asking! I'll give my feedback as a list of answers.

1. I am very happy with the moderators.
2. Yes, they definitely do treat users well.
3. I cannot think of anything they should stop doing.
4. They could start including Koine Greek in the scope of this website :)
5. I think our site is mostly drama-free.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I really appreciate it. Concerning #5, Greek drama is on-topic. ;)